# Why is gulp minifying?

Tags: gulp

Even after removing the uglify from my gulp.js file, it keeps outputting minified javascript. It also runs in milliseconds, making me think it's somehow caching the files. Can I force gulp to redo the tasks completely even though my files haven't changed?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-csso');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('css', function(){
  return gulp.src([
    ... bunch of css files 
  ])
    .pipe(concat('all.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
});

gulp.task('js', function(){
  return gulp.src([ 
  ...bunch of js files
  ])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'))
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'css', 'js' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question. I seem to have had some typo. At first I had all my paths in subfolders. Now that I have moved all my js files into one folder, then ran gulp, I have no more errors. I also think because some files were already minified before gulp this added to the confusion.

Nothing to see here, move on.